# xcode4 lost auto completion ability after importing three20 libraries with python scripts

Tags: autocomplete, xcode4, three20

The auto completion ability just disappeared when installing three20-install scripts like

http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project

Therefore, even when I type self.  , nothing can appear , but it should pop out the functions with a list.

(my xcode4 is 4.0.1)

Anywhere to correct this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should install Xcode 4.0.2, I think its indexing is more efficient. *(or less bugged...)*
2. Make sure to clear Xcode index in `DerivedData` folder or from *"Organizer window > Projects"*. Then make sure the full project builds, including dependencies, especially `three20`. Eventually, restart Xcode, rebuild, that should fix completion.
3. If none of above works, check that three20 "Header search path" are correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The truth is from here  http://three20.info/article/2011-03-10-Xcode4-Support

Comment: What suggested/explained in your link is what I was suggesting in point 3. :) Anyway, great news that finally works.